# cURL & Paypal WPS

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm trying to submit to Paypal Website Payments Pro through cURL. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
    // set vars 
    $cmd = "_cart";
    $upload = "1";
    $business = "seller_1298211815_biz@nowhere.com";

    $req = "cmd=$cmd&upload=$upload&business=$business";
    $req .= "&".postToEncoded($_POST);

    $url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; // test
    // $url= 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; // live

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $res = @curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_err = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

I've tried a ton of options read different places and I have yet to get this to work. I just want to be able to pass my extra vars to Paypal then continue on loading the PP site with the added vars. The post is working fine, but I don't know how to get it to go to the PP site!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you post more info?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. The net panel in firebug shows to post to the intermediate page (above script) is working and if I echo out $req it is also well formed. It seems like it just doesn't want to be accepted by paypal (would their server know the difference between a regular post submission and a cURL submission?). Do I need api credentials sent along?

Comment: cURL doesn't send the user to the remote site by design. If you want the user to end up there, just use a regular POST with hidden fields like Serge mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to redirect your customer to a paypal page with your parameters - you can approach this differently. Have your form that makes the POST add 3 hidden fields which you set to your variables, and form's `action` be PayPal's page. That way customer will get there immediately, without PHP.

Would this work for your situation? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I;m trying to keep the paypal variables out of the public pages. I've already tested as above before trying to move the info out into a separate file. I'm working on doing it as a self-submitting form with javascript, but it just seems silly that this a) isn't possible or b) isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: @Thomas - If you need for a customer to interact with PayPal after your submission - it is not possible to do like you described by design (I mean technically it is, but I'm sure it's against the policy). This would expose security vulnerabilities, as you will need to collect information, like customer's password, on your page. No one should enter paypal password on any domain but paypal.com. Without the information on what you're trying to achieve in the end it's hard to advise you the right solution. PS: the variables you mentioned are not secret; why are you hiding them?

Comment: "the variables you mentioned are not secret; why are you hiding them?" - well, because data is valuable, indentity theft is rampant. Why hand someone half of the the login to one's paypal account (which is collecting money) if you don't have to? If I could obfuscate that, a malicious user may still be able to get it, but at least I'm not handing them the keys myself.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem and I end up creating my own set of classes for integration with PayPal. I wrote a detailed tutorial on [how to integrate PayPal Website Payments Standard with your custom PHP shopping cart](http://www.softarea51.com/blog/how-to-integrate-your-custom-shopping-cart-with-paypal-website-payments-standard-using-php/).